# How can we get/calculate all the available FinancialIndicators outside TradingChart and InteractiveTradingChart?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, data, dataset, financialdata

How can we get/calculate **all the available** `FinancialIndicators` outside `TradingChart` and `InteractiveTradingChart`?

Using `InteractiveTradingChart` we can retrieve and add valuable data from an asset for our study with something like:

```
InteractiveTradingChart[{"GOOGL", {{2022, 1, 1}, {2023, 1, 1}}}]
```

or

```
InteractiveTradingChart[FinancialData["GOOG", "OHLCV", {{2022, 1, 1}, {2023, 1, 1}}]]
```

There we can add and use **100** different financial indicators (`FinancialIndicator[]`) as the following:

```
{AbsolutePriceOscillator,AccumulationDistributionLine,AccumulativeSwingIndex,Aroon,AroonOscillator,AverageDirectionalMovementIndex,AverageDirectionalMovementIndexRating,AverageTrueRange,ChaikinMoneyFlow,ChaikinOscillator,ChaikinVolatility,ChandeMomentumOscillator,CloseLocationValue,CloseLocationValueVolume,CommodityChannelIndex,CommoditySelectionIndex,DemandIndex,DetrendedPriceOscillator,DirectionalMovement,DynamicMomentumIndex,EaseOfMovement,FastStochastic,ForceIndex,ForecastOscillator,FullStochastic,Inertia,IntradayMomentumIndex,KlingerOscillator,LinearRegressionSlope,MarketFacilitation,MassIndex,MESAPhase,MESASineWave,Momentum,MoneyFlowIndex,MovingAverageConvergenceDivergence,MovingAverageConvergenceDivergenceHistogram,NegativeVolumeIndex,OnBalanceVolume,PercentagePriceOscillator,PercentageVolumeOscillator,Performance,PolarizedFractalEfficiency,PositiveVolumeIndex,PriceVolumeTrend,ProjectionOscillator,QStick,RandomWalkIndex,RangeIndicator,RateOfChange,RelativeMomentumIndex,RelativeStrengthIndex,RelativeVolatilityIndex,RSquared,SlowStochastic,StandardDeviation,StandardError,StochasticMomentumIndex,SwingIndex,TimeSegmentedVolume,TRIX,TrueRange,UltimateOscillator,VerticalHorizontalFilter,Volume,VolumeRateOfChange,WilliamsAccumulationDistribution,WilliamsPercentR,AccelerationBands,BollingerBands,SimpleMovingAverage,HullMovingAverage,DoubleExponentialMovingAverage,ExponentialMovingAverage,ParabolicStopAndReversal,VolatilitySystem,WeightedMovingAverage,LinearRegressionTrendlines,LinearRegressionIndicator,MedianPrice,VariableMovingAverage,TriangularMovingAverage,TripleExponentialMovingAverage,TimeSeriesForecast,KeltnerChannels,TypicalPrice,MovingAverageEnvelopes,PriceChannels,ProjectionBands,RaffRegressionChannel,StandardDeviationChannels,StandardErrorBands,WeightedClose,WildersMovingAverage,Close,High,Low,Open,HighestHigh,LowestLow}
```

How can we get/calculate all of these indicators from our data?

```
data = FinancialData["GOOG", "OHLCV", {{2022, 1, 1}, {2023, 1, 1}}]
```

Or how can we extract the data from the `TradingChart` or `InteractiveTradingChart` so we can use them separately?

We are specially interested in using the `OHLCV` among with the `FinancialIndicator` data to apply and train some ML models.

Answer (score 3):

It seems there's a way to do it, luckily :)

```
data = FinancialData["GOOG", "OHLCV", {{2022, 1, 1}, {2023, 1, 1}}]

financialIndicators = AssociationMap[ FinancialIndicator[#][data] &, FinancialIndicator[]];

(*financialIndicators = ParallelMap[<|#1 -> FinancialIndicator[#1][data]|> &, FinancialIndicator[]]*)
```

P.S.: Now applying the suggestion from @JoshuaSchrier.

Comment: You could alternatively try something like:
`financialIndicators = AssociationMap[ FinancialIndicator[#][data] &, FinancialIndicator[]];` to simplify the creation of the association.  (This is also about 3x faster than `ParallelMap`) .

Comment: Oh, that's interesting @JoshuaSchrier, I'm going to try it here ;)